# Class adminhtml/catalog_product_helper_form_msrp_enabled does not exist error when mass updating product attributess

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

I am running **Magento 2.2.2** and whenever I try to mass update product attributes, it gives me a whitescreen right after trying trying to get to the mass update screen from the product grid.

I checked the logs and the error is: **main.CRITICAL: Class adminhtml/catalog_product_helper_form_msrp_enabled does not exist [] []**

Module **Magento_Msrp** is enabled. I searched for a `Enabled.php` class, but could only find classes with that name in other modules (CMS, Analytics and Multishipping) ... maybe thats the problem, but why?

Any idea how to fix that or where to start looking?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Class catalog_product_helper_form_msrp_enabled is Magento 1's

Please check in eav_attribute table, look for column including "model" and see if any of these columns has a catalog_product_helper_form_msrp_enabled value.

If yes, try editing it to Catalog/Product/Helper/Form/Msrp_enabled

Let me know if this helps!